# Platform for Storing TBs of Time Stamped Data

Tags: bigdata

We have a system that creates a lot of data, up to 1.5 million time stamped records, about 24MB, per second or about 2TB per day.

The data comes from multiple sources and has multiple formats, the one thing in common is the time stamp.

Currently we save about 5 days of data in files and have in-house software that generates reports.

We are contemplating creating a scalable system that can hold and query years of data.

We're leaning towards something like what Nathan Marz describes in [How to beat the CAP theorem](http://nathanmarz.com/blog/how-to-beat-the-cap-theorem.html), using Hadoop/ElephantDB for long term batch storage and Storm/Cassandra for a realtime layer.

I'm wondering if the community can point out any alternatives or suggest further reading?

Does the fact that our data is primarily organized by time lend itself to a particular type of solution?

Is there a better forum to ask this kind of question?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to do aggregated / batch reports, or you also need some kind of real-time access. If so - please give some examples of the access patterns

Comment: We need both aggregated / batch reports and real-time access. Typically users request time based reports. Whats the value of this item (or these items) over time t1-t2. What times have a particular item value been out of range.

Comment: what is a size of data to be aggregated for the single report?

Comment: Have a look at OpenTSDB which addresses storing mass amounts of time series data. http://opentsdb.net/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

It is tough problem to have both real time access and scalable batch processing in the same time. 
While there is no perfect solution I would explore two following capabilities:
a) Hive, with partitions by time and subpartitions by some other key (like client id or something similar). This solution will give you:

Good performance for data import
Good throughput on the aggregated reports
Probably acceptable time of one sub partition access. Although - it will never be 1-2 seconds.

b) Brisk. It is hadoop with cassandra replacing HDFS. It promised to give you all you need, although i would expect data load performance and batch reports performance to be inferior to the vanilla hadoop - because it built specifically for it.